# Advantage of using Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the **advantage** of using

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(job);
```

than

```
job.run();
```

where `job` is an instance of `Runnable` class.

Comment: Why do you want to use this?Have you google it or not?

Answer (score 16):

Writing literally

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(job);
```

is pointless: it's just the wrong way to do

```
new Thread(job).start();
```

As opposed to the latter, the former will leave the thread hanging on until the Executor Service is finalized.

The advantage of using an Executor Service comes about when you keep it around as an instance/class variable and reuse it for many submitted tasks. The Executor Service must be properly `shutdown` when you are done with it (see boilerplate code [on Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), and see [`close`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#close())).

More generally, the difference between submitting tasks to an executor service and just running the tasks is in the achieved concurrency. Whether that results in any advantage is highly specific to the job being submitted: it may also be useless or even broken (causing data races, deadlocks, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

The difference is same as in `new Thread(job).start()` and `job.run()`. When you submit the job for execution, the job runs in one of the available thread of the executor. Calling `job.run()` is simply like any other method call which does not run in a separate thread but rather on the calling thread.

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantage is that Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor reuse the Thread instance to speed up the starting of the other jobs.

Comment: But that doesn't happen if you don't reuse the Executor. If you execute the whole line `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(job);` the call is pointless.